# What does custom0_subscribe() function do in InvenSense SensorStudio?

Tags: sensors, sensormanager, sensor-fusion

I am writing a custom sensor in InvenSense SensorStudio and noticed the custom0_subscribe() function?  How does it work and when would I want to use it?

Comment: Unfortunately, *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are off-topic"* - please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and consider refactoring this to prevent closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom0_subscribe() works like other subscribe functions. It is used when you want to get data from a custom sensor from another custom sensor (eg: custom sensor 1 connected to custom sensor 0).